# How do I pass configuration like server addresses to Rust tests?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I want to code a crate for a REST API. `cargo test` needs a server where the features can be tested, so I need something like adding "parameters" to the tests.

I looked at the documentation of `cargo test` to see if I can add command line options like `cargo test -- --api-server=https://localhost:80` but it doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: Use environment variables.

Comment: You could easily have your test read an environment variable. Then you'd do `TEST_SERVER='localhost:80' cargo test`

Comment: Environment variables are really the right tool for this job, because you want to set them once and use them for all test runs in the specific environment. And that's exactly what you can do in your IDE, or shell, and in the build server either globally or per build (build parameters are usually passed as environment variables too).